# Pygame - How to find a certain color in a surface

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating an Asteroids video game and am having some trouble. Firstly, for the shooting ship i'm using a triangle, where the top most and bottom most pixels are marked with a color different slightly different. Instead of the top pixel having an RGB value of (255, 255, 255) as it should, it's value is (254, 255, 255), to make a slight difference to identify it easier. The problem comes with the rotation. When the ship is rotated, the pixels are not in the same spots, and i need them for the shooting. The ship is rotated using

```
pygame.transform.rotate(playerImage, currentRotation)
```

My question is, how do i look for a specific color inside of a surface?
I've tried this method:

```
for i in range(playerImage.get_height()):
    for i in range(playerImage.get_width()):
        if playerImage.get_at((j, i)) == (255, 255, 254, 255):  # the other 255 is the alpha value
            topDot = [j, i]
        if playerImage.get_at((j, i)) == (254, 255, 255, 255):
            bottomDot = [j, i]
```

The code does work, but it is super slow, and slows down the rest of the program. Is there a way to speed this up using a different method?

Comment: Can you not calculate the position of the top and bottom since you know the rotation?

Comment: This appears to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the way you're attacking the problem, no: finding which of a skillion pixels has a give value, you must access each pixel.  If the image had other properties, where pixels were dependent on nearby values, you might use those to improve a search, but not as you've stated it.

However, you do have on obvious solution: use the rotation parameters to *compute* the location of the desired pixel.  The rotation algorithm might differ with your computation by 1 in any direction, but you'd be almost on top of the desired location, in any case.  You'd have no more than 9 pixels to check.

Apply the well-covered rotation equation, and work from there.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like a good solution. I'll try it out and update you on the results.